# Get HH:MM:SS from datetime2 by giving seconds

Tags: formatting, datetime2

I search a command that give formated time like `HH:MM:SS` when I give just seconds.

As example, if the search command is `\formatetime{}`, it should give the following result:

```
\formatetime{50}   % should print “50”
\formatetime{60}   % should print “1:00”
\formatetime{3661} % should print “1:01:01”
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it with some calculations with the aid of `intcalc`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{intcalc}

\newcommand\formatetime[1]{%
    \def\ss{\intcalcMod{#1}{60}}%
    \def\mm{\intcalcMod{\intcalcDiv{#1}{60}}{60}}%
    \def\hh{\intcalcDiv{#1}{3600}}%
    \ifnum\hh=0\else\hh:\fi%
    \ifnum\mm=0%
        \ifnum\hh=0\else{00:}\fi
    \else
        \ifnum\mm<10%
            \ifnum\hh>0%
                {0\mm}%
            \else
                {\mm}%
            \fi%
        \else\mm%
        \fi:%
    \fi%
    \ifnum\ss<10{0}\fi\ss%
}

\begin{document}
    \formatetime{50}   % should print “50”
    \formatetime{60}   % should print “1:00”
    \formatetime{3661} % should print “1:01:01”
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, youre answer is usefull, but the question was alredy answerd https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291212/command-to-display-time-duration-in-human-readable-form

Comment: OMG, I've invented the wheel from scratch!:D