# Minutes command in TeX

Tags: tex-core, primitives

Someone told me, minutes were accessible in TeX, but I cannot find a command to call this.

How do I call minutes in TeX?

Please do not tell me about the construction of minutes out of `\the\time`, I know how to do that.

Please: Answers only for TeX, not LaTeX.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291212/command-to-display-time-duration-in-human-readable-form/

Comment: Please: Answers only forTeX, not LaTeX. Without packages.

Comment: “do not tell me about the construction of minutes out of `\the\time`”: then how? That's the only way to access the minutes from within TeX

Comment: So there ist no command like /minute in TeX?

Comment: @MatthiasBorck-Elsner No, the only time-related primitives are `\year`, `\month`, `\day`, and `\time`.  With e-TeX (any TeX except Knuth's `tex`) you can define `\def\minute{\numexpr\time-60*\numexpr\time/60\relax\relax}` then `\the\minute`, but that's just a macro emulation on top of `\the\time`.  With Knuth's TeX you can also get the minute, but it's less easy

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik ok

Comment: @MatthiasBorck-Elsner What is it with extracting the minute from `\the\time` that doesn't do what you want?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I believe your definition of `\minute` is not *entirely* correct: `\numexpr` rounds, while `\divide` truncates. No difference in the first half hour, but after that... `;-)`

Comment: @campa They say even a broken clock is right twice a day :)  Indeed, you're right.  A quick fix is `\def\minute{\numexpr\expandafter\minuteaux\the\numexpr\time-60*\numexpr\time/60;} \def\minuteaux#1;{#1\ifnum#1<0+60\fi\relax}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\newcount\timebase
\timebase=\the\time
\newcount\hour
\hour=\the\time
\divide\hour by 60
\newcount\minute
\minute=0
\newcount\second
\second=0
\newcount\reduce
\reduce=60
\newcount\start%  
\newcount\stop%  
\def\while[#1,#2,#3]{%  
  \start=#1 %  
  \stop=#2 %  
  \def\doit{#3}%  
  \loop \ifnum\start<\the\stop \doit \advance\start by 1\repeat%  
  \start=0 \stop=0}%   
\while[0,24,\ifnum\the\hour=0 \else\ifnum\the\hour=\the\start\multiply\reduce by \start \vskip\baselineskip\advance\timebase by -\reduce\fi\fi]%  
\minute=\the\timebase

Output:

The Time: \the\time%

Current time: 
\ifnum\the\hour<10 0\fi%

\the\hour:%

\ifnum\the\minute<10 0\fi%

\the\minute:%

\ifnum\the\second<10 0\fi%

\the\second


Seconds are not defined yet.
\bye
```

Comment: Why don't you write shorter `\minute=-\hour \multiply\minute by 60 \advance\minute by \time`?

Comment: ...and...why did I get negative scores  for this question?

Answer (score 8):

I give much simpler calculation of `\minutes` and `\hours` than egreg:

```
\def\hours{\numexpr (\time+30)/60-1\relax}
\def\minutes{\numexpr \time-60*\hours \relax}

\the\hours, \the\minutes

\bye
```

Answer (score 3):

> Well, there *might* be, with some recursion magic.

Here it is then, a `\minute` macro that works in *ANY* engine :)

It differs from wipet's `\minutes` because his macro emulates a TeX register which you can access with `\the`, while with this one you can't, because Knuth's TeX doesn't have fake registers like ε-TeX's `\numexpr`.

```tex
\catcode`\@=11
\def\minute{\number\expandafter\min@i\the\time{}{}{};}
\def\min@i#1#2#3#4#5;{\min@ii#1#2#3#4;}
\def\min@ii#1;{\ifnum#1>59 \expandafter\min@ii\number\min@decr@hour\else #1\fi}
\def\min@decr@hour\else#1\fi{\fi\min@reverse#1{}{};}
\def\min@reverse#1#2#3#4#5;{\min@minus@sixty#4#3#2#100;}
\def\min@afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi\min@re@reverse#1{}{};}
\def\min@re@reverse#1#2#3#4#5;{#4#3#2#1;}
\def\min@minus@sixty#1#2#3#4#5;{\ifcase#2
     \min@minus@one{#3}{#4}{#14}\or\min@minus@one{#3}{#4}{#15}%
  \or\min@minus@one{#3}{#4}{#16}\or\min@minus@one{#3}{#4}{#17}%
  \or\min@minus@one{#3}{#4}{#18}\or\min@minus@one{#3}{#4}{#19}%
  \or\min@afterfi{#10#3#4}\or\min@afterfi{#11#3#4}%
  \or\min@afterfi{#12#3#4}\or\min@afterfi{#13#3#4}%
  \fi}
\def\min@minus@one#1#2#3{\ifcase#1 \min@minus@one{#2}{}{#39}% 0
  \or\min@afterfi{#30#2}\or\min@afterfi{#31#2}\or\min@afterfi{#32#2}%
  \or\min@afterfi{#33#2}\or\min@afterfi{#34#2}\or\min@afterfi{#35#2}%
  \or\min@afterfi{#36#2}\or\min@afterfi{#37#2}\or\min@afterfi{#38#2}%
  \fi}
\catcode`\@=12

\edef\x{\minute}\show\x

\end
```

The algorithm is really stupid.  It takes the tokens from the expansion of `\the\time`, and successively subtracts 60 from that, until what remains is less than 60, and returns that.  The subtraction, in the lack of `\numexpr`, is done by a ten-way `\ifcase` that looks at the tens digit of the number, and returns the value subtracted (no arithmetic was harmed in the making of this code :)

Comment: +1 because it also works with experimental LuaMetaTeX. Nice :)

Comment: @JairoA.delRio Oh, cool! (not too surprising, as this uses really basic TeX constructs, but cool nonetheless)

Comment: Does not work. Is this a fully functioning example?

Comment: @MatthiasBorck-Elsner It _does_ work. See the log file.

Comment: @MatthiasBorck-Elsner Yes, it uses primitives available in TeX since early versions (1982 likely, but I'm not sure.  Works on modern systems, definitely).  The `\show` command pauses TeX to ask for interaction, so if you run from an IDE, that won't work.  Try replacing the line `\edef\x{\minute}\show\x` by just `\minute`

Answer (score 2):

There is no expandable way to access the time in hours and minutes in Knuth TeX, which can only do arithmetic via register assignments.

Well, there *might* be, with some recursion magic.

It's much easier if you allow e-TeX extensions:

```
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\minutes{\computeminutes\time}
\def\computeminutes#1{%
  \ifnum#1<60
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#1}{\expandafter\computeminutes\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-60\relax}}%
}
\def\hours{\expandafter\computehours\time}
\def\computehours#1{\the\numexpr(#1-\computeminutes{#1})/60\relax}

\def\longtime{\printlongtime\time}
\def\printlongtime#1{%
  \ifnum\computehours{#1}<10 0\fi\computehours{#1}%
  :%
  \ifnum\computeminutes{#1}<10 0\fi\computeminutes{#1}%
}

\hours, \minutes, \longtime

\computehours{955}, \computeminutes{955}, \printlongtime{955}

\computehours{905}, \computeminutes{905}, \printlongtime{905}

\computehours{37}, \computeminutes{37}, \printlongtime{37}

\computehours{0}, \computeminutes{0}, \printlongtime{0}

\bye
```

Why doing the long way? Because division in `\numexpr` rounds, rather than truncate.

[image]

The final examples are meant to emulate different times.

With `expl3` (that can also be used in plain TeX):

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \minutes { \int_to_arabic:n { \c_sys_minute_int } }
\cs_new:Npn \hours { \int_to_arabic:n { \c_sys_hour_int } }
\cs_new:Npn \longtime
 {
  \int_compare:nT { \c_sys_hour_int < 10 } { 0 }
  \hours
  :
  \int_compare:nT { \c_sys_minute_int < 10 } { 0 }
  \minutes
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```